# I overstayed for 1 day in South Africa and got 'undesirable' but I have to transit through the Johannesburg airport

Tags: air-travel, transit, overstaying

I have been classified as undesirable in South Africa on September 30 but I have to go through Johannesburg airport on October 18 back from Botswana to Malaysia. Will I be allowed to transit through the country?

Comment: Where are you travelling from?

Comment: I'm traveling from Botswana to Malaysia using qatar airlines so Ihave to transit via OR Tambo

Comment: What is your citizenship?

Comment: [Related.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/46995/transit-visas-for-south-africa-undesirable-overstay-tourists)

Comment: Were you successful with your transit through JHB?